# Problem installing restbed!

Tags: software-installation, 22.04

I am trying to install restbed on my linux Ubuntu 22.04 jammy. I am running the following commands to install it

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install librestbed-dev
```

but I am getting an error

```
E: Unable to locate package librestbed-dev
```

I also tried

```
sudo apt-get install librestbed-dev
```

but it also fails.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WczvN.png)

Can anyone help and tell what is the problem here?

Comment: I think I know the problem, the package does not exist for Jammy distribution, only for focal, as I checked in https://packages.ubuntu.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess because of libssl1.1 is not ported to jammy, this package didnt ported yet. I am able to install it in jammy with the packages of focal.

Here are the download links

```
root@ubuntu-host ~ ➜  lsb_release  -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/restbed/librestbed-dev_4.0~dfsg1-5build2_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/restbed/librestbed0_4.0~dfsg1-5build2_amd64.deb
   
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb 
dpkg -i librestbed0_4.0~dfsg1-5build2_amd64.deb 
dpkg -i librestbed-dev_4.0~dfsg1-5build2_amd64.deb 

root@ubuntu-host ~ ✖ apt list librestbed-dev
Listing... Done
librestbed-dev/now 4.0~dfsg1-5build2 amd64 [installed,local]

root@ubuntu-host ~ ➜
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. I checked the package and I found it is not released for Jammy that is correct. But I did not use the focal release. Instead I did clone the repository and build it locally, then exported the path to build and include in the .bashrc, using CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables. Thank you for your help.